# Show subsequent hidden elements on click

Tags: jquery

I have a few divs which are hidden except the first one. I don't want it to loop. On click of a button I want -

1. display the next div. (eg: Since first div is already displayed, on first click second div, on third click second div and so on)
2. hide the prev div again which was made visible

I am trying this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").click((function(){
    var counter = 1;
    return function()
    {  
     
        $('.test').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).index()+1;
        if( counter == index && ($(this).css('display') != 'none')){
           $(this).hide();
        }
        if (counter == index && ($(this).css('display') == 'none' && counter < 6){
            counter++;
            $(this).show();
            
        }

       })
       
    }
    })());
});
```

```
<div class="test">TEXTA</div>
<div class="test">TEXTB</div>
<div class="test">TEXTC</div>
<div class="test">TEXTD</div>
<div class="test">TEXTE</div>
<div class="test">TEXTF</div>

<button id="show"></button>
```

It is only working on the first click. How to fix this? If there is a simpler way to this please suggest that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is much more complicated than it needs to be. There's no need for IIFEs or even a loop.

The simplest way to achieve your goal is to place a CSS class on the element to be displayed, and then on the click of the button remove that class from the active element and apply it to the next sibling. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#show").on('click', e => {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.test { display: none; }
.test.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test active">TEXTA</div>
<div class="test">TEXTB</div>
<div class="test">TEXTC</div>
<div class="test">TEXTD</div>
<div class="test">TEXTE</div>
<div class="test">TEXTF</div>

<button id="show">Next</button>
```